# Specific row selection depending on column values

Tags: pandas, row, selection

In the following df I must select all rows where column x == 249 (1.condition) and then I must find all dt in a range between 655 to 665 (2.condition). As you can see the column "x" contains also other values and the column "dt" is a cumsum result. And I only need the entries where value is equal to 249 and then I need the entire rows where dt is between 655 and 665 (but only after value==249). All other rows can be droped. Some Background: the value 249 is an action and I need the values after this event between 655s and 665s (after the event). I hope my problem is clear and I am very thankfull for any help or hints.

```
timestamp             value       x         dt      
2018-01-01 15:07:14      2      249         2
2018-01-01 15:07:17      3      0           5
2018-01-01 15:07:19      2      0           7
2018-01-01 15:07:22      3      0           10
2018-01-01 15:07:24      2      0           12

.
.
.
2018-01-01 15:18:04      2      0           655
.
.
. 
2018-01-01 15:18:14      2      0           665
.
.
.
2018-01-01 18:07:14      2      7           1
2018-01-01 18:07:17      3      0           65
2018-01-01 18:07:19      2      0           77
2018-01-01 18:07:22      3      0           100
2018-01-01 18:07:24      2      0           125
.
.
.
2018-01-01 18:18:14      2      0           665
.
.
.
2018-01-01 20:07:14      2      249         22
2018-01-01 20:07:17      3      0           53
2018-01-01 20:07:19      2      0           77
2018-01-01 20:07:22      3      0           108
2018-01-01 20:07:24      2      0           125
.
.
.
2018-01-01 20:18:14      2      0            665
```

Comment: `df[(df.value==249) & df.dt.between(655,665)]`? Btw, `value==249` or `x==249`?

Comment: Sorry, I mean x == 249 !